# client side validation for asp.net mvc “A potentially dangerous Request.Form…

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I would like to how to implement client side validation for a potentially dangerous request.form in asp.net mvc.

I do not want to set `[ValidateInput(false)]` in this case, and it is not user friendly to display this error message page to the user. Something like what the `[Required]` attribute did for client side validation.

I presumed that there is a built in function for this as it seems a common problem to me, but it seems like i am unable to find it.

Comment: Client-side validation will require client-side code. I would recommend using jQuery and the jQuery Validate plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I am aware of the wide range of javascript client side validation available out there, but the concern i am facing here is not to reinvent the wheel for rewriting the validation rule that match the asp.net mvc potentially dangerous request.form, neither to restrict the input to allow alphanumeric only

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about a client-side validation equivalent for this as this goes beyond simple form validation. Request URLs, cookies etc. are also validated by ASP.NET request validation so you would probably have to implement your own JavaScript that hooks into every form post and validates the whole HTTP request before it's sent. Are you sure this is really what you need to do? Request validation is a security feature, not a usability one, so request validation failures should really be treated as exceptions rather than form validation errors.

Comment: You might be overcooking the solution - can you outline specifically what problem you are trying to solve - i.e. what set of values you expect to validate against in an innocent request and  where and how they are submitted?

Answer (score 4):

You can catch the `HttpRequestValidationException`during model binding by overriding the `DefaultModelBinder.BindModel`method.

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Illegal Html characters...");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In your controller action you can now check if the model is invalid and re-display the view as appropriate.  jQuery unobtrusive validation should take care of the rest.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {                               
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

If you don't already have a custom `DefaultModelBinder`you will have to make sure to register it on application start.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomDefaultModelBinder();
```